# Creating a export module for a mean app

Tags: javascript, express

So trying to create a simple module to sort out accounts for a webpage, and thought it would be simple. Create a file with some functions, wrap it all in a module.exports and bobs your uncle. Well, turns out bobs not my uncle.

So created the following file:

```
module.exports = function(lameAccount) {
    lameAccount.initAccount( function ( myId, myName, done) {
        console.log("Will create" + myId);
        console.log("Name is " + myName);
        done(null,false,"This is just a hello");

    })
}
```

And in the part that needs it (the api router)

```
var lameAccountant                    = require('../modules/lameaccount.js')
```

And then call our function

```
lameAccount.initAccount(blockRecord._id, blockRecord.betName)
```

However, when I try to use this functionality I get

```
/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:108
  if (this.ended && !this.hasRejectListeners()) throw reason;
                                                      ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/routes/api.js:119:22)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:175:45)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Promise.safeEmit (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:81:21)
    at Promise.fulfill (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:94:24)
    at Promise.resolve (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:113:23)
    at model.<anonymous> (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1578:39)
    at next_ (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:89:34)
    at EventEmitter.fnWrapper (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:186:8)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:175:45)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Promise.safeEmit (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:81:21)
    at Promise.fulfill (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:94:24)
    at p1.then.then.self.isNew (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:260:27)
    at newTickHandler (/Users/bengtbjorkberg/WebstormProjects/Challange/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:229:18)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

============== Edit in regards to first answer ============

So if this is an anonymous function (certain it i, why does this work)

```
// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {

    // =========================================================================
    // passport session setup ==================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // required for persistent login sessions
    // passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
```

or indeed the apis themselves

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {

    var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
    // parse application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.json())


    app.get('/api/userList', function(req, res){
       User.find({}, {'_id':1, 'userName':1},function(err, users) {
           if (err)
            res.send(err)

           res.json(users);
       })
    });
```

Is that what app.use does, allow you to slide in an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attaching an anonymous function to `module.exports`, so `initAccount` is `undefined`.

Use that anonymous function:

```
var lameAccountantModule = require('../modules/lameaccount.js')

// call the function like you would the anonymous function
lameAccountModule(lameAccount)
```

Or expose the one you want, `initAccount`,  instead:

```
exports.initAccount = function ( myId, myName, done) {
        console.log("Will create" + myId);
        console.log("Name is " + myName);
        done(null,false,"This is just a hello");
}
```

Then in your other file:

```
var lameAccount = require('../modules/lameaccount.js')
lameAccount.initAccount(myId, myName, callback)
```

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to down vote my question rather than your question. Other than that, your answer makes sense, but why does then the passport module work? (added it as an edit)

Comment: Tried it, and it did not work, it still states that undefined is not a function using the exports.initAccount function.

Comment: Got it working this way, think I had a type somewhere as well. Still curious what the difference is.

Comment: So very sorry, now understand, you did not downvote your self, it was someone else. Very sorry, never quite understood what on earth that was about :)